# Get an users location (street, country, etc.) only using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am trying to grab an user's location based on geolocation (or anything else). I do not want to send a call to some server, because that server might go down or become unresponsive.

I can use `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` to get a location coordinates, but I can't use that to actually pin point what the user's address is. [This site](https://locationdetection.mobi/) does a really good job at providing the information, however, they send a call to a server (their own) which probably sends another call to another service.

My questions are:

1. What is the best way to determine an user's country?
2. What is the best way to grab an user's location using `navigator.geolocation`?

User's country HAS to be something local. The exact location CAN be grabbed from a service somewhere else. All I really care about is the country, but grabbing the exact location would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: **I do not want to send a call to some server** This seems unreal since you are not a provider of big data relative to geolocalisation. You will need a webservice like Google API or something else to adress a gps position to an adress.

Comment: @Zeratops Can Google's API get a location based on the geolocation though? As I said on the last paragraph, if necessary, I can grab the user's address through a service (like Google's API).

Comment: Apparently yes : `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452` and it would gives a json object with some best place it found regarding your gps position (more information by  [following this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro?hl=en#ReverseGeocoding)).

Comment: @Zeratops Oh yeah you're right. Not bad. I noticed it doesn't require an API key... I wonder if I'll get limited at some point?

Comment: I recommend creating the whole process of : google account + activate the API in your developper dashboard. Here you will then be able to track how many queries you requested per days, per month, ... and eventually the limit per month.

Comment: @Zeratops Yeah you are right. I already created my API key, but I then noticed it didn't require an API key at all. For development purposes, I'll stick to no key. Thanks!